# Visual Studio generates an odd file tree when deploying C# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, publish, directory

Is there a way to control what files and how files are deployed when an application is publisehd?

I'm writing a Windows Form application using C#. I'm using the publish function to create the installation files and install the application. When the application is installed, however, it seems to install the files in a bunch of different folders instead of just one place. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8.1.

The application is being installed in the user's `AppData` folder, which is fine, but from there the tree looks like this:

```
AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data\XW1K5QEX.XAT\QT90D7HP.HRR\aprs..tion_6e18985c58ead43c_0001.0000_19946cd48dfad6aa\Data\1.0.0.0
```

This folder contains `user.config` and that's all

```
AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\VZL1JHLE.0GG\LXJZWQB7.8JG\aprs...exe_6e18985c58ead43c_0001.0000_en_8cf5993e048f7d9e
```

This folder contains two files `application.exe.config` which I think has the default user settings and the application icon.

```
AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\VZL1JHLE.0GG\LXJZWQB7.8JG\aprs..tion_6e18985c58ead43c_0001.0000_19946cd48dfad6aa
```

This folder seems to have all the application files I need except `user.config` it has duplicates of `application.exe.config` and the application icon.

```
AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\VZL1JHLE.0GG\LXJZWQB7.8JG\manifests
```

This last folder contains two `.manifest` and two `.cdf-ms` files which are also in the folder above.

I can't figure out why so many folders are being created, why I have 8 `.manifest` files `.cdf-ms` files, 2 icon files and 3 `.config` files.

I was hoping to have the application installed in one or two folders:

```
AppData\Local\Application Name
```

and maybe:

```
AppData\Local\Application Name\Data
```

That's it!

I've spent a few hours on Google trying to work this out, but I keep finding suggestions on how to change the location for installing Visual Studio, not app created with Visual Studio.

If the application is installing artifacts from items removed from the project, there must be a way to clean that up too.

Thanks!

Comment: Creating a professional installation package for a Windows program is a whole art in itself, and can take almost as long as creating the program if the installation scenarios are even slightly complicated. I recommend the WiX installer, but it takes a while to learn it. The "one click" installation has, I believe, some limitations - at least that's what the WiX people say. :-)

Comment: By the way, it's not typical to install programs in AppData. That's where applications are supposed to place their work files and so on. Programs are normally installed in Program Files or Program Files (x86). Installing a program the wrong place can lead to problems with the dreaded UAC.

Comment: @RenniePet thank you for the feedback. I"m not far enough into the development for a full blow installer, and I have done some of those in the past, but I expected the default publish feature to be far cleaner that it is for simple alpha deployments.

Comment: For a simpler kind of Windows setup program that does not involve Windows Installer (MSI files) I believe this program is quite popular: Inno Setup http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php (I've never tried it myself.)

Answer (score 0):

The "Publish" feature AFAIK works well for web applications. For windows form app, it takes you to create a one click deployment app and so on and doesn't act the same as it does for web projects.

You're better off creating a deployment project or a Wix setup project if you want to control what files are published and which folders they go to.

Also, for WinForms app, the relevant files are copied to bin folder (bin\debug or bin\release), so you can just take that folder and zip it or copy it to deploy the app. You can even do that as Post Build event (batch commands basically).